# Шанс срабатывания\выбора

Tags: php

Есть 3 числа: 1, 2, 3. Но пока что не знаю в каком виде, массив или три переменных. И есть кнопка. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку мне выпадало число 1 с вероятностью 70%, число 2 с вероятностью 25% и число 3 с вероятностью 5%. Надеюсь суть ясна.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовываются подобные вещи на php, если это возможно.

Comment: генерите случайное число от 0 до 99. меньше 70 - 1...

Comment: при помощи range()  заполняете массив 70-ю единичками, 25 двойками, 5 тройками. перемешиваете - shuffle(), берете первое - array_shift ()

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
$n = rand(1,100);

if ($n <= 70) {
  echo 1;
} elseif ($n >= 96) {
  echo 3;
} else {
  echo 2;
}
```